# WinForms control's child form doesn't respond to mouse events when control is on modal dialog

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, modal-dialog, mouseevent

I needed functionality that doesn't exist in the standard ComboBox, so I wrote my own from a TextBox and a form.  When the user types in the TextBox, it shows a dropdown as a separate form.

Here's some of the relevant code:

```
internal class FilteredDropDown : Form
{
    public Control OwnerControl { get; set; }
    public bool CloseOnLostFocus { get; set; }
    protected override OnLostFocus(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CloseOnLostFocus && !OwnerControl.IsFocused)
            this.Close();
    }
    protected override OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseMove(e)
         // highlight the moused over item in the list
    }

    ...
}
public class FilteredCombo : TextBox
{
    private FilteredDropDown dropDown;
    public FilteredCombo()
    {
        dropDown = new FilteredDropDown();
        dropDown.OwnerControl = this;
    }
    public void ShowDropDown()
    {
        if (dropDown.Visible)
            return;
        dropDown.RefreshFilter();
        var loc = PointToScreen(new Point(0, this.Height));
        dropDown.Location = loc;
        dropDown.CloseOnLostFocus = false;
        int selectionStart = this.SelectionStart;
        int selectionLength = this.SelectionLength;
        dropDown.Show(this);
        this.Focus();
        this.SelectionStart = selectionStart;
        this.SelectionLength = selectionLength;
        dropDown.CloseOnLostFocus = false;
    }
    protected override OnLostFocus(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dropDown.Visible && !dropDown.ContainsFocus())
            dropDown.Close();
    }
    protected override OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnTextChanged(e);
        ShowDropDown();
    }
    ...
}
```

There's obviously a whole lot more code than that to deal with all kinds of stuff irrelevent to my question.

The problem is when I put the FilteredCombo on a modal dialog.  Somehow the FilteredDropDown form doesn't receive mouse events at all when it is parented by a modal dialog.

I've read something about WinForms filtering out events on all except the current modal dialog, I suspect that is what's going on, but I have no ideas of how to fix it.  Is there some way to get the mouse up/down/move/click/etc. events to work when parented by a model dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to go digging through the ShowDialog source code, and I found that it calls user32.dll EnableWindow(Handle, false) on all the windows except the shown one.  The problem was that the FilteredDropDown already existed by the time the ShowDialog() method got called.  I discovered two different ways to fix this:

1. Don't allow the DropDown to be shown until the parent form is shown.  This is a bit trickier to guarantee, so I also implemented the second way.
2. Re-enable the DropDown window when it is made visible:

   ```
   [DllImport("user32.dll")]
   private static extern bool EnableWindow(IntPtr hWnd, bool enable);

   protected override void OnVisibleChanged(EventArg e)
   {
       base.OnVisibleChanged(e);
       if (this.Visible)
       {
           EnableWindow(this.Handle, true);
       }
   }
   ```